# How can I check if a number is in a range without using if statements? Python

Tags: python, arrays, loops, if-statement, boolean

I want the function to return true when a number falls within a set range, like [2,9)
My first thought was to use a for loop like this

```
def in_an_interval(number):
    for i in range(2, 8):
        return print(bool(i==number))
```

but it only returned true for the first value, 2
Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: You hardly need a custom function here, the builtins are sufficient:  `result = number in range(2, 8)`

Comment: Why not simply `2 <= number < 9`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess you could abuse another conditional, if you can't use "if" for some reason.

```
def in_an_interval(number):
    while number >=2 and number < 9:
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: To whoever downvoted me, it would be nice if you explained why my answer is not a useful answer to the question "How can I check if a number is in a range without using if statements?"

Answer (score 1):

If you're running Python 3 and working on integers, you can use the `in` operator on a `range` object directly:

```
def in_an_interval(number):
    return number in range(2, 9)
```

This is very fast (simple math calculation) because `range` objects has a `.__contains__` method. Also note that `range` does not include the end, i.e. `range(2, 8)` is actually "2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7" here, so I changed it to `range(2, 9)` for you.

If you actually mean "numbers", including floating point numbers, then you'd better use comparison operators:

```
def in_an_interval_float(number):
    return 2 <= number < 9
```

There's no chance you test for an arbitrary floating point number with `range` because it's a wrong tool for this job.

---

Your current code is wrong because it returns out of the whole function at the first iteration of the `for` loop:

```
def in_an_interval(number):
    for i in range(2, 8):
        return print(bool(i==number))
```

You probably want to return *only when found*, and return `False` when not found:

```
def in_an_interval(number):
    for i in range(2, 8):
        if i == number:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: Andrew said "number", not integer, and this answer won't work for floats.

Comment: @AaronBentley Sounds sensical. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For integers, you hardly need a custom function, the builtin `range` is sufficient:

```
result = number in range(2, 8)
```

Although it is probably overkill for most use cases, you could define a small class that works for floats:

```
import math

class Interval:
    def __init__(self, start, end):
        assert start <= end
        self.start = start
        self.end  = end
    def __contains__(self, number):   # this dunder method lets you use 'in'
        return self.start <= number < self.end


interval = Interval(math.e, 2 * math.pi)
print((2 * math.e) in interval)
print((4 * math.e) in interval)
```

#### output:

```
True
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution when your number is not necessarily an integer:

```
def in_an_interval(number):
    return number >= 2 and number < 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Or this:

```
def in_an_interval(number):
    return 2<number<9
```